# What does DynamoDB's scan really cost?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm using Dynamodb to store `users` like this:

`Users: uuid(Primary Key) joined_at(Sort Key) full_name`

I'd like to paginate through thousands of users sorted by `joined_at` in batches of 20 users.

I wanted to use `scan` operation for this but I heard it literally reads all of the table (which would be very costly on read units).

Is that true? how do I just consume 20 reads at a time?

*P.S. using `query` on the hand requires me to filter by the ID of a single user which is not what i want.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination is available using query in dynamoDB. You have to implement as explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination). The problem in pagination is DynamoDB is you cannot get the total count of items in the table. To solve that you can maintain a separate table and store the items count that are in the tables.

The next and previous page is evaluated by

```
{ 
"TableName":"users",
"ScanIndexForward":true, // false implies get data before the sort key
"KeyConditionExpression":"#hkey = :hvalue AND #rkey > :rvalue",
"ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#hkey":"uuid","#rkey":"joined_at"
},
"ExpressionAttributeValues" :{ 
":hvalue":1094,":rvalue":0
},
"ExclusiveStartKey":{
     "uuid":"<your-uuid>","joined_at":<your published at data>
},
"Limit":10
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - although my question was more about how scan counts read units. if you have a table of 10,000 records and you scan with a limit of 10 - do you get charged 10k reads?

Comment: It costs you with 10 reads.

According to [Reduce Page Size](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanGuidelines.html#QueryAndScanGuidelines.SpikesOfActivity)

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon DynamoDB pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/) is based upon **provisioned capacity**. You choose the amount of Provisioned Throughput for Reads and Writes and you will be charged for this capacity.

When performing a large scan, you will consume a lot of the capacity. It will not cost you money, but it will consume the capacity you have provisioned and other users might be impacted because there is insufficient capacity to service their requests at the same time. Your scan might also take a long time because it can only Read at the rate defined by your provisioned capacity.